# Mysql select max variable value

Tags: mysql, variables, max

I have a temporary table and the following query:

```
Select *,  @rnkma:=IF(age>17 and age<22,@rnkma+1,@rnkma),
          @rnkmb:=IF(age>21 and age<25,@rnkmb+1,@rnkmb),
          @rnkmc:=IF(age>24 and age<30,@rnkmc+1,@rnkmc),
          @rnkmd:=IF(age>29 and age<35,@rnkmd+1,@rnkmd),
          @rnkme:=IF(age>34 ,@rnkme+1,@rnkme)  from tmp_user where gender='M';

    Select @rnkma, @rnkmb, @rnkmc, @rnkmd ;
```

The result is:

```
@rnkma  @rnkmb  @rnkmc  @rnkmd
  5        8       3       4
```

I want to get max value of this result like:

```
@rnkmb
  8
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: share your SQL code first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using CASE and GREATEST():

```
SELECT 
CASE GREATEST(@rnkma, @rnkmb, @rnkmc, @rnkmd)
    WHEN @rnkma THEN '@rnkma'
    WHEN @rnkmb THEN '@rnkmb'
    WHEN @rnkmc THEN '@rnkmc'
    WHEN @rnkmd THEN '@rnkmd'
END name,
GREATEST(@rnkma, @rnkmb, @rnkmc, @rnkmd) value
(...)
```

Comment: Never seen `GREATEST()` before +1

Comment: oh fantastic Pawel, but one more thing how can i find which variable (name) is the greatest.

Answer (score 1):

@Pawel's answer is correct , i will add just one thing as a reference.
There's a difference between `Max()`  and `Greatest()`

`MAX()`  returns maximum value of an expression. Ex:

```
select max(Age) from staff;
```

`Greatest()` returns the greatest of the list of exprs. More than one column must be given.

```
SELECT GREATEST(150,160,161) FROM XXX;  will return 161
```